# Beginner requests Help with Mysql and C#

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm trying to build a program that uses a C# to work with a MySQL DB. I get the C# syntax, and  can write the language, but I don't have much experience with the libraries, and I feel a bit lost.

Could someone post examples of how a program would be built (in technical terms, syntax would be nice, but pseudo code is fine, too)?

I understand the theory of how it works, but need a hands on approach to it.

Thank you.

*EDIT*

I forgot to add that I want to learn how to do it with the .NET v.2.0 framework / VS2005 / MySQL v5.0 combination.

**EDIT # 2**

2.0 .NET will only be supported. =)

Comment: Do you have any specifics we could work off of?  This question is a little general.  What kind of program?  I assume you're using Visual Studio, have you poked through the templates that there are there?

Comment: Oh yes, I do. I want to be able to read and write data, and display the data from a mysql DB using a C# GUI program. The mechanics of how that is done, with code examples would be awesome. Like, if a button is pressed, read from a given row of the database, and display it inside a textbox. Also, how would the program be written? Do I need to write libraires? how do I include them? etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is tutorial for [Entity Framework + MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/connector-net-tutorials-entity-framework-winform-data-source.html).

There are lots of other ways to operate with DB, depending on what you need:

1. If you need execute raw sql queries against DB - use OdbcConnection + OdbcCommand
2. Need to manipulate items in DB as objects - use ORM ([EntityFramework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa697427.aspx), [NHibernate](http://nhforge.org/Default.aspx), [Linq2Sql](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb425822.aspx))
3. Like old-style DB interop? - [DataSets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.aspx) is your choice.

I really like EF. Easy thing to start with.

---

PS: And before mixing UI and DB-interop, please read about [Separation of concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns). MVC is interesting to read about too. About "libraries": create another project in your solution and add DB-interop logics there. Don't mix it in one assembly, because when your project becomes bigger than "Hello DataBase!" application it will create a big mess in code and logics, really.

UPDATE:
Using VS2005 and .net 2.0 is mysterious idea, really. Lots of tools and assemblies where made since 2.0 release. Linq, Orm-s, etc. Live without them is hard and all the benefits of C# are lost. I highly recommend to use latest techniques, if there is no strict reasons to use 2.0.

If using SqlServer - ObdcCommand and OdbcConnection can be replaced to SqlCommand and SqlConnection. (thanks @Abe Miessler comment)

Comment: +1 - I'm using EF1 + MySQL in a system that's been live for about 6 months, and although there were teething issues before v6 of the Connector, the linq functionality is pretty good now, make sure you use the latest Connector (currently 6.3.5) here: http://www.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/

Comment: @Pablo - Ooops... Didn't see ".Net Framework 2.0" line... For 2.0 EF and Linq2Sql are unavailable. Do you have any special reasons why you intend to use 2.0? 4.0 is richer and much more useful. Linq is introduced starting 3.0 and it is very helpful, when working with DB.

Comment: I just got my job first as a programmer. Very entry level. I know how to do the basics (from book examples), but I want to learn about working with Data Bases. It is required to use .NET 2.0, something I will try to change, but have little hope for. I'm not asking for you to do my work, just give me examples so I can study them and learn. I just feel a little overwhelmed about the whole situation. 1st time in a professional environment.

Comment: Hope you'll manage to remove '2.0 only' restriction. It would save a bunch of time. I would say that developement-cost is 10 times higher, using 2.0.

Comment: SqlConnection and SqlCommand will not work with a MySQL Database.  They are specific to SqlServer

Comment: @Abe Miessler - Do you know if OdbcConnection is compatible?

Comment: @Abe Miessler - you are right, will change to OdbcConnection and OdbcCommand

Comment: Yes, the Odbc equivalents should be used.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the help! I think the change to .NET 3.0 is hard to sell, because there are some machines running Win 2000 Server. From what I've researched, only .NET 2.0 is compatible with them. It really irks me, because the systems engineer doesn't even know what he really wants, and he is always out. I will try my best, because I really want to do a good, reliable program, but working with management who knows nothing about software, makes it a bit difficult. You all know how it is. BTW, I'm reading the book Pro C# 2005 and the 2.0 .NET platform to gain some quick knowledge.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example swiped from MSDN:

```
public void InsertRow(string connectionString, string insertSQL)
{
    using (OdbcConnection connection = 
               new OdbcConnection(connectionString))
    {
        // The insertSQL string contains a SQL statement that
        // inserts a new row in the source table.
        OdbcCommand command = new OdbcCommand(insertSQL, connection);

        // Open the connection and execute the insert command.
        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
        // The connection is automatically closed when the
        // code exits the using block.
    }
}
```

If you want to read records in a DB, look at this example:

```
public static void ReadData(string connectionString)
{
    string queryString = "SELECT DISTINCT CustomerID FROM Orders";

    using (OdbcConnection connection = new OdbcConnection(connectionString))
    {
        OdbcCommand command = new OdbcCommand(queryString, connection);

        connection.Open();

        // Execute the DataReader and access the data.
        OdbcDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("CustomerID={0}", reader[0]);
        }

        // Call Close when done reading.
        reader.Close();
    }
}
```

FYI i am just copy/pasting these directly from MSDN.  I highly recommend reading over their documentation and looking at their examples if you are just getting started.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.odbc.odbcdatareader.aspx

Comment: Thanks for that. Now, how do I tie that to a button click event, and populate a textbox with the data? Where would such code go? In Main, or as a separate library? Different namespace than the one that has the Main() code?

Comment: Double click on the button in design-mode.  This will create the button click event.  Place the code you want to execute in there.  The first example if for inserting data. If you want to select data look at the second example.

Comment: Oh, and Mr. Miessler, I will mark the question above yours as the answer. The gentleman provided me with some extra valuable tools. Yet, you were the one who clarified a big problem I had with working with GUIs. So, instead of some points on some websites, you get something more valuable: My appreciation. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a blog post getting you started with MySql and C#.

http://blog.bobcravens.com/2010/06/the-repository-pattern-with-linq-to-fluent-nhibernate-and-mysql/

Hope that gets you started.

Bob

Comment: Linq is not available in .Net 2.0